# Expressing sum using simple formula (without summation)

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, binomial-coefficients

Express by a simple formula not containing a sum:

$$\sum\limits^{n}_{k=1} \binom{k}{m}\frac{1}{k}$$

I figured that

$$\sum\limits^{n}_{k=1} \binom{k}{m}\frac{1}{k} = \frac{1}{k}\sum\limits^{n}_{k=1} \binom{k}{m}$$

So I could use 
$$\binom{m}{m} + \binom{m+1}{m} + \binom{m+2}{m} + \cdots + \binom{k}{m} = \binom{k+1}{m+1}$$

$$\sum\limits^{n}_{k=1} \binom{k}{m}\frac{1}{k} =  \frac{1}{k} \binom{k+1}{m+1}$$

Is this derivation correct?

Comment: You cannot pull a parameter being summed outside of a summation. Looking at the last equation, there's simply no way to 'plug in' values of $k$ on both sides.

Comment: ok, it makes sense, if it were something independent of the summation, only then would it work :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice that ${k\choose m}\frac{1}{k} = {k-1 \choose m-1}\frac{1}{m}.$
Then $$\sum\limits^{n}_{k=1} \binom{k}{m}\frac{1}{k}= \sum\limits^{n}_{k=1} \binom{k-1}{m-1}\frac{1}{m}.$$
Shifting the index, we can use the identity $\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\binom{k}{m-1}=\binom{n}{m}.$
So $$\sum\limits^{n}_{k=1} \binom{k}{m}\frac{1}{k} = \frac{1}{m}\binom {n}{m}.$$

Comment: stupid question: how did you arrive at the first identity? did use some known identity or figured it from the algebraic expansion of k choose m?

Comment: Yup the algebraic form of $k \choose m$. The $1/k$ cancels leaving $(k-1)!$ in the numerator. Then we express $m!$ as $m(m-1)!$ to have a binomial coefficient.

Comment: ok, thank you very much, I started with that but didn't figure out that I could get to m - 1 that way.

Comment: I made a mistake and forgot to shift the upper index. I edited it now.